How to Properly Configure This DNSSEC Setting?
enter image description here
As shown in the picture, the DNSSEC setting is not configured. I might be misunderstanding something, and any guidance on how to set it up correctly would be greatly appreciated.
Additional Information:
The link is as follows: https://dnsviz.net/d/dolstep.com/dnssec/
I'm not sure where it went wrong. Ever since the domain transfer, from the moment the new registrar took over, the domain connection hasn't worked no matter what I try. Even after changing the name server to gcloud DNS, it similarly says there is no DNSKEY, and it shows that the A Record, CNAME Record, and TXT Record I registered are missing.
I verified this using the tool provided by Google:
https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/?lang=ko
I need help. Thank you.
The steps I have tried are as follows:

Created a zone using Google Cloud DNS and changed the name server to this one. I registered A Record, TXT Record, and CNAME Record in gcloud DNS and tried to connect, but it failed.

Tried to manually register DNSKEY, but the connection still failed.


